# Tool for creating (My)SQL table from CSV header (no script)

Tags: mysql, csv

I have to make some queries on several Excel sheets and I think it would be easier if I can put them on a DB and make the queries with SQL.

Is there a tool that creates SQL tables from a CSV file with headers?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has functions built in to [load data from CSV files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html). This is probably your best option and one that gives you the most control.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Data Import tool](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) (Excel, CSV or TEXT formats) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Import allows to create new table and customize fields in a wizard.